# WebApp Auth Azure AD Settings is stuck

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I mistakenly deleted the Azure AD application linked to my WebApp. Then I wanted to link it to a new one but the Azure AD Settings page keeps loading and looks stuck.

I tried to turn the authentication Off and then On again to see if it would restore the Azure AD to "Not Configured", but it doesn't work.

Here is a picture of my Auth Config:
[image: Auth config]

Here is a picture of my Azure AD Config (nothing is clickable):
[image: Azure AD config]

For now the only solution I have is to either disable the Auth completely or make a new WebApp. Is this a known bug?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to restore the auth or disable it completely?

Comment: Restore it, but it's fixed now. I'll explain it below. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
I deleted the application in Azure AD on Friday. Then I noticed the login didn't work anymore the following Monday. And today (Tuesday) it works again. The Auth settings page isn't stuck anymore and I could easily go in the "Advanced" tab and switch the ClienId to a valid one.

Not sure what the issue was, but it's fixed now.